# Check if Skype is installed

Tags: c#, skype

I have tried to fix a method that checks if the user has Skype installed on his computer. This I fixed / come up with:

1. I have Skype installed on my computer
2. I've fixed a method that loops through all of my installed programs
3. My method finds my installed programs BUT it can not find skype although it is installed. But my method finds other programs that are in the same directory.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to check if Skype is installed on the computer?

The method I used are simillrar to this one:

[Method to loop through all installed programs](http://mdb-blog.blogspot.com/2010/09/c-check-if-programapplication-is.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use the registry:

```
using Microsoft.Win32;

    //Function uses Microsoft.Win32 to check registry value of
    //HKEY_CURRENT_USERSoftwareSkypePhoneSkypePath and returns false if
    //the key is null
    private bool isSkypeUser()
    {
        RegistryKey skype = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SoftwareSkypePhone");

        if (skype != null && skype.GetValue("SkypePath") != null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

http://brcline.com/blog/?tag=skype

**EDIT:**

A dirty workaround is to loop through the StartMenu folders looking for the Skype shortcut or folder. You must use the following SpecialFolder enumeration:

```
var startMenuPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonPrograms)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This might work. Just make sure that the registry value is removed after uninstall. Otherwise you might get false positives.

Comment: I have tried that method but that one does not work for me.. I done really know why... @ssg How do I check if the registry value still exists?

Comment: Uninstall Skype from your computer and see if the value stays or gets removed. If it stays that method won't work. You can try other registry keys relevant to Skype. You can monitor registry activity by using ProcMon from Sysinternals.

Comment: @AwmaN: From the link above: _"To check if Skype is installed, in regedit check if the following key exists: HKCUSoftwareSkypePhone, SkypePath . This key points to the location of the skype.exe file. If this key does not exist, check if the HKLMSoftwareSkypePhone, SkypePath key exists. If the HKCU key does not exist but the HKLM key is present, Skype has been installed from an administrator account but not been used from the current account."_

Comment: If the above doesn't work for you, you might also want to try checking the following key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\skype\shell\open\command  But this will only tell you if skype is installed on the machine.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: it would be prudent to check that the path referred to in the registry still exists too in case the user has manually deleted the install directory.

Comment: I dont really know if I´m doing anything wrong but none of theese keys did work.. It always returns false

Comment: Well, in that case a dirty workaround is to loop through the programs located in the start menu C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs .  Note that the start menu folder will depend on your Windows version so I suggest you use this Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonPrograms) to get the path.